# Do RANGE_ADD mutations have to fetch the whole connection-array each time?

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, relay

I finally got RANGE_ADD mutations to work. Now I'm a bit confused and worried about their performance.

One outputField of a RANGE_ADD mutation is the edge to the newly created node. Each edge has a cursor. `cursorForObjectInConnection()`([docs](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/)) is a helper function that creates that cursor. It takes an array and a member object. See:

```
newChatroomMessagesEdge: {
  type: chatroomMessagesEdge,
  resolve: async ({ chatroom, message }) => {
    clearCacheChatroomMessages();
    const messages = await getChatroomMessages(chatroom.id);
    let messageToPass;
    for (const m of messages) {
      if (m.id === message.id) {
        messageToPass = m;
      }
    }
    return {
      cursor: cursorForObjectInConnection(messages, messageToPass),
      node: messageToPass,
    };
  },
},
```

plus a similar edge for user messages.

Now this is what confuses me. Say you want to make a chatroom app. You have a `userType`, a `chatroomType`and a `messageType`. Both the `userType` and the `chatroomType` have a field `messages`. It queries for all of the user's or chatroom's messages respectively and is defined as a relay-connection that points to `messageType`. Now, each time a user sends a new message, two new RANGE_ADD mutations are committed. One that creates an edge for the chatroom's messages and one that creates an edge for the user's messages. Each time, because of `cursorForObjectInConnection()`, a query for all of the user's messages and one for all of the chatroom's messages is sent to a database. See:

```
const messages = await getChatroomMessages(chatroom.id);
```

As one can imagine, there occur lots of "message-sent-mutations" in a chatroom and the number of messages in a chatroom grows rapidly.

So here is my question: Is it really necessary to query for all of the chatroom messages each time? Performance-wise, this seems like an awful thing to do.

Sure, although I did not look into it yet, there are optimistic updates I can use to ease the pain client-side - a sent message gets displayed immediately. But still, the endless database queries continue.
Also, there is Dataloader. But as far as I understand Dataloader, it is used as a *per request* batching and caching mechanism - especially in conjunction with GraphQL. Since each mutation should be a new request, Dataloader does not help on that front either it seems.

If anyone can shed some light on my thoughts and worries, I'd be more than happy :)

Comment: Did you found a solution for that?